# PHP - script that add an ordered field on database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a field and insert an increment value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695217/add-a-field-and-insert-an-increment-value)

I have this table on my database in mysql:

```
id   ref     data
1    111     data1
2    111     data2
3    111     data3
4    111     data4
5    222     data1
6    222     data2
7    222     data3
8    333     data1
9    333     data2
```

and I'd like to insert a new field, called for example *order*, where for each ref, I'll set a crescent value. So the output should be :

```
id   ref     data    order
1    111     data1   1
2    111     data2   2
3    111     data3   3
4    111     data4   4
5    222     data1   1
6    222     data2   2
7    222     data3   3
8    333     data1   1
9    333     data2   2
```

how can I do it? Update seems to me undefined.. so I should order them following the id of the table...

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP.  Editing/maintaining the database schema is generally done entirely within the database.  PHP would just be the application which uses the database (and would need to be updated for the new schema, generally).

Comment: Why have you started a new thread? OMG Ponies has already answered you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695217/add-a-field-and-insert-an-increment-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not name the field `order` that is a reserved word in MySQL and it is a hassle to use reserved words as field names.
Let's name it `rank`.

```
-- first add new field.
alter table table_name add column rank int(3);

-- then fill the field with a rank.
set @rank = 0;
set @ref = null;
update table_name set rank (
  select rank from (
    select 
      if(@ref <> ref,@rank:= 1,@rank:= @rank+1) as rank
      if(@ref <> ref or @rank = 1,@ref:= ref, ref) as dummy
    from (
      select ref from table_name order by ref, id
    )

  )
);

-- use the following select to get the next rank to insert.
select @newrank:= max(rank)+1 as newrank from table_name where ref = '333';
```

Comment: It's not a hassle, you just use \`backquotes\` around your identifiers, which you should be doing anyways

Comment: Still all this stuff complicates things (if only slightly), and complications lead to a higher chance for errors and time spend debugging. Better to not use reserved words IHMO

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the new field to your table, here is the syntax (although I am not sure I fully understand your question):

```
alter table `table_name` add column `order` int(3);
```

Comment: Yeah, but it doesnt add the progressive index...